# Django: active Home link

Tags: django

This is my first project with django, I wanted my static site html/css/js to turn it into a dynamic website. However, in navMenu I want to have 'home' link only if the user is not on the index page.
Here is my attempt:

```
<style>
    #hm{
        display:none;
    }
    .activate{
        display:block;
    }
</style>
        <div id="navMenu" class='py px'>
            <ul>
                {% url 'home' as home_view %}
                <li id = 'hm' {% if request.get_full_path != home_view%} class = 'activate' {% endif%}>Home</li>
                <li class='brd'>Alumni</li>
                <li class='brd'>Staff</li>
                <li class='brd'>Services</li>
                <li class='brd'>About</li>
                <li><a id='btnSearch' href="#"><i class="fa fa-search searchUpdate"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

the urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from pages.views import home_view
from events.views import events
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_view, name = 'home'),
    path('events/', events, name = 'events')
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a content block with and adding it only to the templates that you want to have the url on

If you dont know how to do that then it goes like this

```
<div id="navMenu" class='py px'>
    {% block urls %}{% endblock urls %}
</div>
```

Then, for all of the pages that you want the url to be on, make a new template with:

```
{% block urls %}

    <ul>
        {% url 'home' as home_view %}
        <li id = 'hm' {% if request.get_full_path != home_view%} class = 'activate' {% endif%}>Home</li>
        <li class='brd'>Alumni</li>
        <li class='brd'>Staff</li>
        <li class='brd'>Services</li>
        <li class='brd'>About</li>
        <li><a id='btnSearch' href="#"><i class="fa fa-search searchUpdate"></i></a></li>
    </ul>

{% endblock urls %}
```

Comment: I can't see the menu at all. https://ibb.co/jhJj1fC

Comment: are you using a base.html with templates that build on that? because if not then try look up some tutorials like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDwdMDQ8oX4 which will show you what my answer is doing. if you can't see the menu then it's because you're not using the template which has the block filled in